# Why After first load symfony stop working?

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.2

I'm new to symfony
and when installation finish the welcome page work correctly but when i'm refreshing the page the load doesnt finish!

[image]

*EDIT :*
For my server configuration i juste use the "php bin\console sever:run" commande to launch my project.
And I add the content of dev log file :

> [2019-02-14 00:09:05] php.DEBUG: Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu. ) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"C:\\Mes Sites Web\\awema\\awema\\vendor\\symfony\\web-server-bundle\\WebServerConfig.php\",\"line\":139,\"trace\":[{\"file\":\"C:\\Mes Sites Web\\awema\\awema\\vendor\\symfony\\web-server-bundle\\WebServerConfig.php\",\"line\":54,\"function\":\"findBestPort\",\"class\":\"Symfony\\Bundle\\WebServerBundle\\WebServerConfig\",\"type\":\"->\"}],\"count\":1})"} []
>   [2019-02-14 00:09:17] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at C:\Mes Sites Web\awema\awema\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 139 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /\" at C:\Mes Sites Web\awema\awema\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php:139, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\NoConfigurationException(code: 0):  at C:\Mes Sites Web\awema\awema\vendor\symfony\routing\Matcher\Dumper\PhpMatcherTrait.php:172)"} []
>   [2019-02-14 00:09:18] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"6b922e"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/_wdt/6b922e","method":"GET"} []

Comment: You should provide the configuration of your server and the logs concerning your problem (in the folder of your server and those in your symfony project at "your_project/var/log").

Comment: @Alex83690 , Its done , i hope its that you asked

Comment: Do you have an error or some output in the terminal window in which you run the server ?

Comment: Is the command `php bin/console cache:clear` command working correctly? The site works again after?

Comment: the commande work correctly yes , and the website is launched  correctly only the first time , and if you try to reload or click on debug bar , you got an infinite load @Alex83690

Comment: nothing in the sever terminal , all is correct @tchap

Comment: You should try to create a route with the "/" path (controller and associated view) to see if that corrects the problem. Your problem may be with the Symfony start page.

Comment: @AWEMAAgenceWebMarketing hi, i have the exact same problem. Did you managed to solve it? THaaaaanks

Comment: I forget how this story was end but the answer below look not bad. since i have't use symfony again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the exact same issue (Windows, Symfony 4.4.2, php 7.1.3)

I was using the WebserverBundle which gives a notice :

> WebserverBundle is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. The new Symfony local
>   server has more features, you can use it instead

If you run for instance

```
 symfony server:start
```

This will propose the installation of the new symfony local server, which solved this infinite loop problem for me.